# Reuse pointer to const strings in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

Is this valid and recommended way of reusing const char * in C?

Context: I am writing test case which requires calling the same function twice but using a different C style char string, where string serves as the ID to the begin and end function of the testing API.

```
    const char *str = "String1";'
    CTX *c = new_context();

    BeginCase(c, "%s", str);

    if (!SUCCESS(c, func1(...)))
        goto out;

    if (!SUCCESS(c, func2(...)))
        goto out;

    EndCase(c, "%s", str);

    str = "String2";

    BeginCase(c, "%s", str);

    if (!SUCCESS(c, func1(...)))
        goto out;

    if (!SUCCESS(c, func2(...)))
        goto out;
out:
    EndCase(c, "%s", str);
    end_ctx(c);
```

Comment: Yes, it is valid. If it's recommended or not depends on your use case...

Comment: Initializing with NULL is pointless if the next thing you do is assign "string1" to it. Just initialize it with "string1" from the start.

Comment: "Reusing" suggests that you are trying to micro-optimize. I dare say techniques like that are generally NOT recommended (unless needed in highly specific context).

Comment: This can't be answered without any context. You should also narrow down the question to either C or C++, since using C strings in application-layer C++ is often considered bad practice.

Comment: Reusing variables for multiple purposes is a pretty reliable way to introduce bugs. Variables, particularly of primitive types, are very cheap.

Comment: You are allowed to do this if you want to.

Comment: Need more context. Anyway in C++ `std::string` should be used or since C++17 at least `std::string_view` (which is more close to `cosnt char*`).

Comment: It's hard to tell what this question is about. Is it about difference between mutable pointer to `const` data vs `const` pointer to mutable data? Or is it about reusing variables?

Comment: Creating a new pointer is no more expensive than assigning a new value to an old one. So you are not saving anything by the reuse.

Comment: I have now updated the question with a bit more context

Comment: IMO your code is perfectly valid. And your usecase also looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Why not just use a string literal directly? `BeginCase(c, "%s", "String1");` Why do you need the variable? It only makes the argument harder to track.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. because then we need to repeat `"String1" in `EndCase(c, "%s", "String1");`

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, that's what I want. I want to see which case starts and ends where. And on top of that, you can't use this `goto` driven control flow. Win-win.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks for your insights, unfortunately I cannot avoid the `goto` control flow. This goes to some FOSS project, and that is how things are done there.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this valid

Yes.

> and recommended way

"Recommended" depends on context. I would never recommend using `NULL` in C++11 or later since `nullptr` obsoleted it. For large functions, re-using a variable for multiple purposes can make it harder to understand. Initialising a variable and not modifying it is simpler and can be preferable in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax specifies that ptr points to a constant character, not that ptr is constant. You can do this, but whether or not you should depends on the situation and needs context that can't be derived from your post, but there is nothing implicitly wrong with this.